# I am getting a "float object not callable" error when calling last function in a class module

Tags: python, class, oop, runtime-error

This is my first attempt at writing a functional program using a class and objects using Python 3.6. What I am trying to do is get input as a list of numbers and return the number of items, the sum, the average, and the variance. Here is my code so far:

```
>>> class stats:
    aList2 = []
    def __init__(self, aList):
        self.aList = aList
    def n(self):
        return len(self.aList)
    def total(self):
        return sum(self.aList)
    def average(self):
        return sum(self.aList)/len(self.aList)
    def sqr_diff(self):
        for i in range(0, len(self.aList)):
           self.sqr_diff = (self.average() - 
           self.aList[i])**2
           stats.aList2.append(self.sqr_diff)
        return sum(self.aList2)
    def variance(self):
        return (self.sqr_diff()/(self.n() - 1))
```

This works great until I get to the variance function:

```
>>> s = stats([5.0,7.0,10.0,12.0])
>>> s.n()
4
>>> s.total()
34.0
>>> s.average()
8.5
>>> s.sqr_diff()
29.0
>>> s.variance()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#250>", line 1, in <module>
    s.variance()
  File "<pyshell#244>", line 17, in variance
    return (self.sqr_diff()/(self.n() - 1))
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
>>>
```

What I have done to try and fix it is to make the sqr_diff module return a float by

```
return float(sum(self.aList2))
```

That did not seem to change the error message at all. I'm at a loss as to what it could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have a variable and method both named `sqr_diff`.  In the `variance` method `sqr_diff()` is overwritten with the float variable defined in the method.

To prevent this from happening in the future you could adopt a naming convention such as: `CamelCase` for classes, `mixedCase` methods and functions, and underscore separated variable names.

**Either change one of these method or variable names to solve this issue.**

Comment: And I know variable and method names are supposed to be different. Thank you, that worked! Not sure how on Earth I missed it.

Comment: @Jabernet No problem! If this answered your question don't forgot to accept this answer or if there is anything else please let me know! :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that when you call the function self.sqr_diff() again, the return value can't read.
Maybe the GLP block the value, sorry I don't know the reason. But I change your code, and it just works.

```
def variance(self):
    if self.aList2 == []:
        return (self.sqr_diff()/(self.n() - 1))
    else:
        return (sum(self.aList2) / self.n() - 1)
```